# Get postion of group in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table created on this link [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e630c6) as you can see there. There are names with points and a day when it was executed. I would like to add for every day how these people were finished in that day. It should start from 1 (you can see it in 'Rank') for every day. And the result should be like below in 'Result':

```
Result
      ID |    date     | Rank | Name
      ---------------------------------
      1  | 2013-10-01  | 1    | Tom
      2  | 2013-10-01  | 2    | Karen
      3  | 2013-10-01  | 3    | Lucy
      4  | 2013-10-02  | 1    | Karen
      5  | 2013-10-02  | 2    | Tom
      6  | 2013-10-02  | 3    | Lucy
      7  | 2013-10-03  | 1    | Tom
      8  | 2013-10-03  | 2    | Lucy
      9  | 2013-10-03  | 3    | Karen
      10 | 2013-10-04  | 1    | Tom
      11 | 2013-10-04  | 2    | Lucy
      12 | 2013-10-04  | 3    | Karen
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL doesn't have the row_number() function, but you can fake it with variables.

```
select
    t.id,
    t.datum,
    t.rank,
    t.name
from ( 
    select
        s.id,
        s.datum,
        s.name,
        s.points,
        If(@datum <> s.datum, @rank := 1, @rank := @rank + 1) as rank, 
        @datum := s.datum
    from
        score_table s
            cross join (
            select
                @rank := null,
                @datum := '1980-01-01'
        ) as r 
    order by
        s.datum,
        s.points desc
    ) as t
order by 
    t.id,
    t.rank;
```

**<kbd>[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e630c6/5)</kbd>**